# Not able to upload a file through python

Tags: python, file-upload, http-post, multipartform-data

After several attempts and repeated failures, I am posting my code excerpt here. I keep getting Authentication failure. Can somebody point out what is it that I am doing wrong here?

```
import requests

fileToUpload = {'file': open('/home/pinku/Desktop/Test_Upload.odt', 'rb')}
res = requests.post('https://upload.backupgrid.net/add', fileToUpload)
print res.headers
cookie = {'PHPSESSID': 'tobfr5f31voqmtdul11nu6n9q1'}
requests.post('https://upload.backupgrid.net/add', cookie, fileToUpload)
```

By print res.headers, I get the following:

> CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-length': '67',
>   'access-control-allow-methods': 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT,
>   DELETE', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'content-encoding':
>   'gzip', 'set-cookie': 'PHPSESSID=ou8eijalgpss204thu7ht532g1; path=/,
>   B100Serverpoolcookie=4281246842.1.973348976.502419456; path=/',
>   'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
>   'server': 'Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)', 'pragma': 'no-cache',
>   'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate', 'date': 'Mon,
>   09 Sep 2013 09:13:08 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
>   'access-control-allow-headers': 'X-File-Name, X-File-Type,
>   X-File-Size', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'})

It contains the cookies also. Am I passing the cookies correctly? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing cookies correctly, should be:

```
requests.post('https://upload.backupgrid.net/add', 
              files=fileToUpload, 
              cookies=cookie)
```

See also documentation:

- [Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies)
- [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: Thanks but I still get the following error `[{"error":true,"error_msg":"Authentication Failed"}]`